# Alert message in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am not able to display the alert message when the login credentials are wrong. It doesn't display in the else scope but when i enter the message in the if scope, it displays? Can someone help me?

```
 message:string;

    //login user credentials to authenticate
    submitForm() {


        this.service.login(this.login.username, this.login.password)
            .subscribe(data => {
                if(data == true){


                }else {
                    this.message = "Username or Password Invalid";

                }
            });


}
```

//html

```
  <div *ngIf="message" class="alert alert-danger text-center " style="width: 40%; font-size: 16px" >{{message}}</div>
```

Comment: With comments, show us how it works in if section.

Comment: i would be more interested in knowing the response of service.
Does the service returns true / false or JSON  ?

Comment: Does it even hit the else section?

Comment: I think you should change `this.login.username, this.login.password` to `this.login.username.value,this.login.password.value`.

Comment: Maybe you should also check if you get into the subscribe function correctly in the first place. For example, it could be your service doesn't use HTTP 200, but something like HTTP 401. And then you should use the error block of subscribe

Comment: @ParthGhiya it returns a Json and a retry:true  if my credentials are wrong

Comment: @AakashThakur the value is underlined as error

Comment: @ndsmyter i am able to get into the subscribe function.. when i check in my console, i am able to verify.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your service and json?

Comment: @LiskaLiskor so retry true has to  be a part of your JSON !!

so you can do something like data.retry to compare, post your exact JSON .!

Answer (score 0):

You must change the assignment:

```
if (data === true)  is the solution
```

A better Solution is

```
if ( data )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
message:string;
submitForm() {
    this.service.login(this.login.username, this.login.password)
        .subscribe(data => {
            if(!data){
                this.message = "Username or Password Invalid";
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What type of is data?

Comment: it is a string..JSON

Comment: What can it return? Something like ( data -> "You are logged!" )?

Comment: i don't get you

Comment: What Can data return ( if it's string )?